# SyntaxError:missing ; before statement [PHP array to Javascript Array]

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

This is how I get php array from api using php file_get_contents

```
<?php 
$array=json_decode(file_get_contents("https://www.example.com.my/sandbox/api/mobileapp.php?token=123123&action=listing_for_map"), true);
$arr= json_encode($array['get']);
?>
```

Here how I put the php array to javascript array and how I get the data

```
   var geoPoint = '<?php echo $arr ;?>';

    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; ++i) {
      var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(geoPoint.get[i].google_coordinate)
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        draggable: true,
        icon: markerImage
      });
      markers.push(marker);
    }
```

Each time I run the code, I got this error. SyntaxError:missing ; before statement

[image: Error]

Can anyone tell me where actually I did wrong? Thank in advance

Comment: No semicolon after  var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(geoPoint.get[i].google_coordinate) ?

Comment: @HZS I tried it, but still got the error.

Comment: Double quote for `var geoPoint = "<?php echo $arr; ?>";` And like HZS said, semicolon after `var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(geoPoint.get[i].google_coordinate);`. Give it a try.

Comment: doesn't need to be quoted at all `var geoPoint = <?php echo $arr; ?>;`

Comment: @AdrienLeber Thank that help me !

Comment: @Ghost Thank that help me !

Comment: Please read [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)
 — Don't just edit the question title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping your JSON in single quotes defines it as a string. You want it to be defined as an object:

```
var geoPoint = <?php echo $arr ;?>;
```

As others' comments pointed out, you are also missing a semicolon on this line:

```
var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(geoPoint.get[i].google_coordinate);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a semicolon after `var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(geoPoint.get[i].google_coordinate)`. It should be `var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(geoPoint.get[i].google_coordinate);`